# Toggle menu in mobile version: vue with pug

Tags: jquery, html, vue.js, pug, toggle

Hej i have a problem with toggle my hamburger menu, my console throw an

error: nav is not defined

header.pug

```
header.site-header
div.navbar
    div.navbar__link.navbar--brand  logo
    div.navbar__link.navbar--toggle
        buttton(@click='toggle(nav)') menu

    nav.nav.navbar__items.static(:class="{'nav--active': active.nav}")
        div.navbar__link language
        div.navbar__link one
        div.navbar__link two
        div.navbar__link three
```

main.js

```
data: {
    active: {
        nav: false
    },
}

methods: {
    toggle (element) {
        this.active.element = !this.active.element
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should slightly change button click handler:

1. In pug markup to `buttton(@click="toggle('nav')")`. Because in your example `nav` is determined as variable, it should be passed as string instead.
2. And in methods you change property incorrectly, it should be:

   ```
   toggle (element) {
       this.active[element] = !this.active[element]
   },
   ```